# How to shutdown udp socket in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, udp

I have a socket listener thread running and it supposed to close when a particular condition is met.here is my code snippet.

```
 def __init__(self, arg):

        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        receiver_port = int(<port>)
        listen_addr = (<some ip>, receiver_port)
        self.socket.bind(listen_addr)
        self.shutdown = threading.Event()
        self.shutdown.set()

 def kill_function():

       self.socket.shutdown(socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
       self.shutdown.clear()
       self.socket.close()
```

I am facing

```
OSError: [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected error when I try to 
kill the socket.
```

The same issue is observing if I user SHUT_RD, SHUT_RDWR.
can anyone please help me how to call shutdown() function, while using UDP sockets.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, you are having a method (`__init__`) and a function (`kill_function`, no `self`) on the same level?

Comment: @KlausD. yes kill function has the self, it's a typo mistake

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> self.socket.shutdown(socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
> ```

`shutdown` is not relevant for UDP sockets but for TCP.  And, `shutdown` takes only arguments on how to shutdown (`SHUT_RD`, `SHUT_WR`, `SHUT_RDWR`) and not a protocol as you do.

Apart from that, your code binds the UDP socket to a local address but does not connect it to another address, i.e. it can send anywhere using `socket.sendto`. Thus you get the message that the socket is not connected when trying to shut a non-existing connection down.

Comment: How then do I signal a thread polling a UDP socket for new packets that the socket has been closed? Shutdown works well to that end for TCP sockets.

Comment: @AlexGrönholm: I'm assuming that you want to notify some remote application that no more data will be sent on this connection. With TCP you can shutdown the socket which results in the tear down of the connection which involves sending FIN so that the peer knows about the socket closed. With UDP there is no such concept, there is not even a concept of a real connection with UDP. If you need to notify the peer explicitly that you are done you need to define an application protocol with such messages and use it. Fore more about this please  create a new question and don't ask in a comment.

Comment: My question was about notifying a reader when *another thread* is closing the socket, but according to my research this is impossible to do on the socket level and requires some software framework level mechanism.

Answer (score -1):

One way to handle this is to put a timeout on the socket with settimeout(), and handle socket.timeout exceptions raised by recv() or recvfrom(). Normally you will simply retry the recv() in a loop, but each time the socket times out, you have a chance to poll for a shutdown flag, etc.  The downside, of course:

- There will be a delay of as much as the timeout interval for a kill request to complete. The longer the timeout interval, the greater the kill latency.
- During idle time (no packets being received), there will be a small CPU overhead for retries. The shorter the timeout interval, the greater the CPU overhead.

A rough example:

```py
def __init__(self, arg):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        receiver_port = int(<port>)
        listen_addr = (<some ip>, receiver_port)
        self.socket.bind(listen_addr)
        self.socket.settimeout(2.0)
        self.should_stop = False

 def run(self):
       while True:
              if self.should_stop:
                     return
              try:
                     data = self.socket.recv()
                     ...
              except socket.timeout:
                     pass

 def kill_function():
       self.should_stop = True
       self.join()
       self.socket.close()
```

Comment: Poll how? Only by doing another receive. All that a timeout tells you is that nothing arrived.